# Vectorized creation of a 3D matrix by indexing one 2D matrix with another

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, indexing, vectorization

In the below example, I create `result` by indexing the rows of `a` with the variable `index`. I can make this work with a loop:

```
a=repmat(1:6,3,1)';
index=[1:3;2:4];

result=zeros(3,3,size(index,1));
for i=1:size(index,1)
    result(:,:,i)=a(index(i,:),:)
end
```

The given `a` and `index` are:

```
a =
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
     4     4     4
     5     5     5
     6     6     6

index =
     1     2     3
     2     3     4
```

The output should be:

```
result(:,:,1) =
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3

result(:,:,2) =
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
     4     4     4
```

In practice, `a` and `index` are `n*3` matrices, where `n` is very large.

`a` is the node coordinates and the `index` is the triangle face index of the node.

The surface is too big, so **I really need to speed up this loop**.

I have an idea that vectorization could make the code faster. But I could not get the ideal output result, even with some matrix "resize" or matrix rotation functions, like `resize` or `reshape`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this example (and I think the general case), you could use a combination of `reshape` and `permute`.

Note I've used a couple of transpose (`.'`) operations to make the `reshape` work, it might be that you could simplify this but it shouldn't be slow:

```
result = permute( reshape( a(index.',:).', size(a,2), size(index,2), [] ), [2 1 3] );
```

If it's always known that `size(a,2) = size(index,2) = 3`, as implied in your question, then you can of course  make this shorter (but less general):

```
result = permute( reshape( a(index.',:).', 3, 3, [] ), [2 1 3] );
```

Breaking this down,

```
a(index.',:).'          % Gives the 2D results
reshape( ..., size(a,2), size(index,2), [] ) % Convert 2D to 3D, with row and column
                                             % sizes defined by 'a' and 'index'
permute( ..., [2 1 3] ) % We need another "transpose", but that isn't defined in the
                        % 3D case. Use 'permute' to swap the 1st and 2nd dimensions
```

Comment: I just record the speed comparision here for others. My 'a' matrix is 188802*3, and 'index' is 377644*3. The time with the previous loop is approximately 0.9 s; the time use this answer is 0.08s. The vectorization method is obviously much faster.

Comment: @ZhangWei I'm glad I could help, and that it has sped up your code!